# Pass each line of stdout as stdin to a new invocation of a tool

Tags: bash, pipe, stdin, xargs, gnu-parallel

I would like to pipe each line of `stdout` into `stdin` of a separate invocation of another tool - essentially mapping over lines, in bash on the command line.

I know I can loop, but that's a bit verbose for such a simple task, and also slow:

```bash
cat out.ndjson | while read p; do \
echo "$p" | jj key
done
```

I know I could write a performant program `maplines` with such an API myself:

```bash
cat ndjson | maplines jj key
```

where `maplines` reads a line from `stdin` and pipes it to a new invocation of `jj key` for each line.

It's important that `jj key` *cannot* accept the line as an argument. It needs the input as `stdin`.

It would be wasteful to reinvent the wheel if there's a tool already. Or one could write a bash function. Surely something like that exists already.

Basically my question is: how do I implement `maplines` in `xargs` or `parallel`. I researched quite a bit but xargs seems to be unable to pass things as `stdout`.

```bash
cat > out.ndjson <<- EOM
{"key": "line1"}
{"key": "line2"}
{"key": "line3"}
EOM
```

[`jj`](https://github.com/tidwall/jj) is available with `brew install tidwall/jj/jj`, as [binaries](https://github.com/tidwall/jj/releases) or from source. While it shouldn't really matter what the command is, it's useful to test whether an answer works.

Comment: What's wrong with e.g. `cat file | xargs -I{} cmd {}` ? `xargs` has no problem spawning a new instance of a process for each line of stdin.

Comment: If you try `cat file | xargs -I{} /bin/bash -c 'echo $$ ; echo $1' _ {}` for example you'll see it print a different PID for each line it prints out.

Comment: @tjm3772 I may have been not clear enough that the line needs to be _piped_ to `cmd`, not passed as an argument to `cmd`. See the example loop where each line is echoed then piped: `echo "$p" | jj key` I emphasized that point in an edit.

Answer (score 2):

The main reason it's slow is that creating new processes is computationally expensive. Since you want to run a new instance of the tool for each line, some of that slowness is inevitable. But it doesn't need to be *as* slow as your current version, because `echo "$p" | jj key` creates *two* processes per line, one to do the `echo`, and one for `jj`. In bash, you can replace the `echo` with a here-string, and similarly replace the `cat |` with a simple input redirection:

```
while read p; do
    jj key <<<"$p"
done <out.ndjson
```

This should cut the overhead (the time it takes above what the `jj` tool itself takes) in half, meaning it'll run at up to double the speed of the original.

Answer (score 1):

The Bash [mapfile](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-mapfile) built-in may be able to do what you want. Try this [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)-clean code:

```
#! /bin/bash -p

function procline
{
    jj key <<<"$2"
}

mapfile -t -C procline -c 1 <out.ndjson
```